# Is it possible to 'Attach' a view to another and point at it, e.g. help guides

Tags: android

Title mostly explains it all, i'm trying too google my way here but unsure what to search for, 
I want to for instance, attach an arrow pointing at a particular view at runtime?

Should i perhaps find the x/y coords of the desired view and then find the middle of each view and position as required?

a somewhat similar effect can be found here, https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

unfortunately i find it to look absolutely hideous and not work as well as i'd like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips
```

Found exactly what i was looking for.